# How to override an interface that uses a generic method?

Tags: java, generics, interface, overriding

I do not have access to the interface's code; I just know there is a method named `dequeue()` to be overridden in the abstract class which implements it.

The name of the interface is `UrgencyQueue`, and the abstract class is `BaseLinkedUrgencyList`.

below is all the info i have on the interface, a UML pic and javadoc

[image][image]

Below is my attempt to override said method:

```
public <Type> void dequeue(Consumer<Type> action) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Method: not implemented.");
}
```

The declaration of the class includes `implements ''interface''`.

The error produced is:

```
error: name clash: dequeue(Consumer<Type#1>) in BaseLinkedUrgencyQueue and dequeue(Consumer<Type#2>) in UrgencyQueue have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
    public <Type> void dequeue(Consumer<Type> action) {
                       ^
  where Type#1,Type#2 are type-variables:
    Type#1 extends Object declared in method <Type#1>dequeue(Consumer<Type#1>)
    Type#2 extends Object declared in class BaseLinkedUrgencyQueue
```

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the definition of the interface: the declaration line with any type parameters plus the method signature of `dequeue`.  Also please include the declaration line of the implementing class.  I'd like to see how all the type parameters are declared and used, on the class and on the methods, as well as how they're being inherited, if at all.

Comment: It looks like the `dequeue` in the interface is supposed to use the generic type parameter of the class, not of the method.

Comment: @user16320675 that was the issue, I was unaware that it worked like that, thank you so much. Feel free to post that as an answer so you can get credit.

Comment: it is actually @khelwood's comment - I just *concretized* it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `dequeue` specified in the interface is supposed to use the generic type parameter of the class, not of the method.

So if the class declaration looks something like this:

```
public class BaseLinkedUrgencyList<Type> implements UrgencyQueue<Type>
```

then the method implementation should be like this:

```
@Override
public void dequeue(Consumer<Type> action)
```